# Starting steps to build a Database access through web/android app

Tags: android, sql, reactjs, web

Very simple question here; I want to have a database that can be access through the web and through an android APP.

What are the steps that I should take? Is there any good tutorial? I am far from professional in this field and looking for a very simple guidance to where to start.

Should I use an SQL Database and React?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to chose if you can have direct access to the database (insecure) or if you want to access it over a API.
**Access with API**
You can create an API, with which you can access the data of your database. You will find alot of examples and tutorials on the internet. Example: [Create a Restful API](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/secure-rest-api-in-nodejs)
**Make a server-client application**
You can create a server, which is running on a hosting or server-pc, which then queries the database and returns the result to the client. 
With Next.js you can setup such a application easy. [Next JS Website](https://nextjs.org/)
**Direct connection**
If it doesnt matter that users have direct access to database, you can directly connect to the database.
First you need a package, which can access a database. You can decide if you want to make simple queries to the database or if you use a ORM-mapper, which can make data-access easier.
**Database Access Packages**
[MSSQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)
[MySQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)
[Mongo DB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

**ORM**
[Type ORM](https://typeorm.io/)
Install one of these packages and query the database.